# Como detectar interrupções das setas em assembly x86?

Tags: assembly

Estou com dúvida como reconhecer um comando das setas no programa em assembly x86. Por exemplo chamar a proc e ao clicar na seta direita, emitir uma resposta você utilizou seta direita...
Se alguém sabe qual é a interrupção para fazer a comparação de registradores e como fazer agradeço!  Até agora o que achei foi as interrupções  int 16h e 21h, mas não funcionou. Continua não reconhecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Maniero tudo certo? Só queria saber como detectar as arrows keys, tentei pelo código ascii em hexadecimal do espaço por exemplo e não funcionou.

Comment: Sim o cmp faz a comparação, mas preciso saber qual interrupção da tecla pra poder faze-la

Comment: MAO isso depende do hardware que está usando (e só funcionaria num sistema operacional próprio ou um que desse acesso low level a esse tipo de coisa) - como você não descreveu o ambiente (e se está rodando dentro de algum OS) e nem o hardware, fica difícil dar mais detalhes. Uma coisa importante de código de máquina e mesmo do assembly é que em cada hardware funciona de um jeito diferente, e dentro dos OSes modernos, quem cuida de interrupções, portas, etc é o OS, o usuário não tem acesso a isso.

Comment: Obrigado Bacco! Se eu for no chat você pode me ajudar por lá?